# How to sort by year-month-day from ascending using the "sort" command?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort

I want to sort dates in the format `31.12.2023`. Lowest year should be displayed first then lowest month then lowest day.

Is the following code fitting my needs? Seems good on first look.

```
sort -t '.' -k 3.1 -k 2.1 -k 1.1
```

What makes more sense to me though is:

```
sort -t '.' -k 3.4 -k 2.1 -k 1.1
```

But this does not sort the way I want.

EDIT:

Thx for your replies!

@Dan thx for your really detailed explanation. Still have no clue how to struggle with the key option exactly. I tested your code but it mixed still some things up. Maybe it's the way I use it in the variable or maybe the type of content in the strings.

Tried then the hint from @FedKad and this seems working like my -k 3.1 -k 2.1 -k 1.1. Does it mean the same thing as -k 3 -k 2 -k 1?

At the moment I only have entries from 2023 so cant evaluate if year also works but for now with above keys I got sorted how I want it. Maybe it was a fail how I described what I need as result but now I got day lowest to highest and month lowest to highest. For year I will have to wait until 2024 comes :) Here is my output example

07.01.2023

08.01.2023

09.01.2023

21.01.2023

26.01.2023

27.01.2023

02.02.2023

Comment: `-k 3.4` would mean you are only sorting but the fourth character of the year field whereas `-k 3.1` will sort by the whole year field.

Answer (score 9):

I think you misunderstood the `-k` option. The format of the value of the `-k` parameter is the following: `group.start_index,group.end_index`.

The index of the first character of a group is 1. The default value of `start_index` is `1`. The default value of `end_index` is the end of the line, not the end of the group.

```bash
sort -t '.' -k 3.1 -k 2.1 -k 1.1
```

In this first command, you are splitting your groups for sorting like so:

- Group 1 will be `31.12.2023`
- Group 2 will be `12.2023`
- Group 3 will be `2023`

Since you didn't specify the end character, you can see it is using the full value for sorting.

In fact, you can add `--debug` to your command, and it will show you more information.

```bash
$ sort -t '.' -k 3.1 -k 2.1 -k 1.1 --debug dates.txt
31.12.2023
      ____
   _______
__________
__________
```

In your second command, it's a similar issue. However, the year group uses only the last digit of the year. In your example, it only uses `3`.

```bash
$ sort -t '.' -k 3.4 -k 2.1 -k 1.1 --debug dates.txt
31.12.2023
         _
   _______
__________
__________
```

#### Solution:

What you want is the following command:

```bash
sort -t '.' -k 3.1,3.4 -k 2.1,2.2 -k 1.1,1.2
```

This is how it looks with `--debug`

```bash
$ sort -t '.' -k 3.1,3.4 -k 2.1,2.2 -k 1.1,1.2 --debug dates.txt
31.12.2023
      ____
   __
__
__________
```

As a matter of fact, as @jcaron mentions in [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448722/sort-date-is-code-correct/1448727#comment2529151_1448727) below, in this case, the result of your initial command and the one I mentioned as a solution will be the same. The last part of the value would already be sorted and will not affect sorting if you don't omit it.

```bash
sort -t '.' -k 3.1 -k 2.1 -k 1.1
```

Even better, as @FedKad suggests in [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448722/sort-date-is-code-correct/1448727#comment2529035_1448727), you can even omit the starting index as it defaults to `1` anyway.

```bash
sort -t '.' -k 3 -k 2 -k 1
```

Comment: +1 … Very graphic … In a good way :-)

Comment: And what is the difference between your answer and this: `sort -t '.' -k 3 -k 2 -k 1` ?

Comment: +1 for the good explanation and the `--debug` option, but in this case, the end result of `-k 3.1 -k 2.1 -k 1.1` will be the same as `-k 3.1,3.4 -k 2.1,2.2 -k 1.1,1.2` anyway, the additional characters will have no influence on the sort since they are actually already sorted.

Comment: @jcaron That is true. I only wanted to clarify to OP how the `-k` option works. But you're right, I should mention what you said in the answer